# jquery-mobile: How to make page with two independent scrollable areas

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery-mobile and want to separate page into two areas: list and details. So I do it with two-column grid. But sometimes list or/and detail area getting too long for screen and I'd like to have independent scrolling of both areas, preferably with jquery-tools, so that scrolling of one area doesn't affect the other one.

Does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1

Create content divs `data-role="content"` and much as you want directly under `data-role="page`. Set a `max-height` value and `overflow-y: scroll;`.

```
.ui-content {
  max-height: 150px !important;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/L9mWb/)**

### Solution 2

Inside main content div `data-role="content"`, add content divs and override their `max-height` and `overlfow-y` only not the parent content div.

```
.ui-content .ui-content {
  max-height: 150px !important;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/c4ZvW/)**

Comment: If I want to have list with a filter, is it possible to let list scroll and filter input stay on top?

Comment: @Daniel you can fix it, but i'm not sure whether this solution would work on all mobile devices

Comment: maybe the information helps - we want to use phoneGap and all the lists are build dynamically in JS. I thought, that based on your solution, containing wrapper needed for the ul-part of listview. The question is, how to squeeze it into list.

Comment: @Daniel you can also do this dynamically depending on list items length. you can adjust created wrappers height dynamically. I'm trying to fix the filter, but since its created dynamically, it need to be tested thoroughly.

Comment: I think, that wrapper height depends on window height, like here http://jsfiddle.net/96MTK/

Comment: @Daniel true, you need to get screen height minus header and footer, to get the available height. this in case you dont want the page to scroll and only the wrappers of listview.

Comment: @Daniel you can do something like this http://jqueryfordesigners.com/fixed-floating-elements/ to search input  http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/p9SD9/